# Method of Induced Representations for inhomogeneous $SO^+(p,q)$ group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

In [Weinberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521670535) Chapter $2$, he classifies all the irreducible unitary representations of the inhomogeneous Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$ via the method of induced representations. Can a similar analysis be done for the general inhomogeneous indefinite orthogonal group $SO^+(p,q)$? If not, can a similar classification be done by a different method, possibly?